# Improve the way of killing a node after an specific amount of time

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, ros

I am publishing a message to an specific topic and I need it to stop after a set amount of time.The publishing process consist of loop thats continuously sends info to the topic.

This is the loop I need to stop after an specific amount of time given by user input.

```
  while not rospy.is_shutdown(): 
        movement_cmd.linear.x = 0
        movement_cmd.linear.y = 0
        movement_cmd.linear.z = 0 
        movement_cmd.angular.x = 0 
        movement_cmd.angular.y = 0               
        movement_cmd.angular.z = 0 
        rospy.logdebug("Publishing")
        movement_publisher.publish(movement_cmd)
        rate.sleep()
```

**Edit :**

This is the user input

```
time = float(sys.argv[2])
```

For example if *time = 2.5* then the loop should publish for 2.5 seconds, after that it should stop and the code would end.

I managed to stop the loop after sometime by setting the publish frequency to 20hz. This means it will publish every 0.05 seconds , so I added a variable named *counter* and every time the loop publishes it adds +0.05 to the *counter* variable.Then *counter* is compared with *time* and if both have the same value I end the loop using:

```
if counter >= time:
        break
```

Is there a way to improve this by using any other function?

Comment: There are many ways to approach this problem, especially since "user input" is very vague in this case. Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: `if current_time > initial_time + max_duration: break`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try rospy `Timer` class to publish on a topic for a certain period of time. It allows to trigger events at a certain time.

```
def stop_callback(event):
    rospy.signal_shutdown("Just stopping publishing...")

time = float(sys.argv[2]) 
rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(time), stop_callback)

while not rospy.is_shutdown(): 
    movement_cmd.linear.x = 0
    movement_cmd.linear.y = 0
    movement_cmd.linear.z = 0 
    movement_cmd.angular.x = 0 
    movement_cmd.angular.y = 0               
    movement_cmd.angular.z = 0 
    rospy.logdebug("Publishing")
    movement_publisher.publish(movement_cmd)
    rate.sleep()
```

Learn more about how to use `Timer` class from [here](http://www.theconstructsim.com/ros-qa-152-publish-topic-certain-period-time/).